# MongoDB - Remove last character from values of a Field

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Unfortunately all the values of my field in a collection are appended with a semicolon. How do I get rid of the junk ';' through an update query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the value and then update/set it; there is no support for expressions unfortunately.